# Demonstrating Move Constructor Usefulness

Tags: c++, move-semantics, move-constructor, copy-elision

I am trying to demonstrate the usefulness of move constructors in eliminating unnecessary copying.
However, when I run in Release, the visual studio optimizer elids the copy. No copy constructor is called when a move constructor is not available, and obviously move-constructor is not called when one is added.

I can remove the optimizations by running in Debug, but this does not make for a very convincing demonstration for the need for move semantics.

```
struct A { 
    int *buff;
    A() {
        cout << "A::constructor\n";
        buff = new int[1000000];
    } 
    A(const A& a) {
        cout << "A::copy constructor\n";
        buff = new int[1000000];
        memcpy(buff, a.buff, 1000000*sizeof(int));
    }
    A(A&& original)
    {
        cout << "Move constructor" << endl;
        buff = original.buff;
        original.buff = nullptr;
    } 
    ~A() { cout << "A::destructor\n"; delete[] buff; }
};

A getA()
{
    A temp;
    temp.buff[0] = 2;
    return temp; 
}
void useA(A a1) {
    cout << a1.buff[0] << endl;
}

void main() {
    useA(getA()); // i'd like copy-constructor to be called if no move constructor is provided
}
```

Is there anything I can change in the code to prevent the optimizer from being able to do away with the copy, and show how adding a move constructor can prevent a full copy?

**Edit:** Preferably the demonstration should NOT require an explicit move call/cast.

Answer (score 4):

You are running into Named Return Value Optimization(NRVO) which is not mandatory and requires that copy/move ctors are available.

To demonstrate the rule of zero/three/five, move semantics, RVO, copy elision I would use this example:

```
struct A{
char* large_buffer = new char[1024];

~A(){ delete[] large_buffer;}
};

struct D{
    A a;
    int b;
    int* c;
};
D construct_D()
{
    // Obtained somewhere
    A a = {};
    int b = 10;
    int* c = new int[1024];

    // Now we want to construct `D` which should "consume" the values.
    D d{a,b,c};
    // Perhaps do something with that before returning it.
    return d;
}
int main(){
    D dd = construct_D();
}
```

You can now explain that:

1. `b` is copied and that is okay.
2. `A` is broken because naive copy ctor is member-wise and double delete will happen. ( If one does not forget to add `D::~D`)
3. It can be fixed with rule of three.
4. It can be more efficient with rule of five because `a` is never used after constructing `d` and it would be better if it could relinquish its buffer and be "consumed".
5. Explain the role of `std::move` to make that consumption happen. You can rewrite the code interactively to change some variables into temporaries and dig into r-value semantics.
6. Writing five functions is tedious and replacing `char*` with `std::vector` gets us rule of zero, which is nice.
7. `c` copies the pointer, not the buffer, which is desirable in this case but dangerous because someone has to deallocate it later and how `std::unique_ptr` could solve this, or `std::string`, or again `std::vector`.
8. Now some students might ask about whether `D` requires 0/3/5 and how can we also fix that.
9. You can add 3/5 and observe that those calls are not made and explain NVRO and RVO for `return {a,b,c}` and the subsequent construction of `dd`.
10. Also one can always confuse some people with `D dd` not calling the assignment operator.
11. At last you can argue that `construct_D` is too long so you will interactively refactor it into smaller functions while using all the learned concepts - `std::move`, passing by ref,value, RVO.

Overall you can spend a good hour or two just on this example and with the added bonus of spreading the `std::` propaganda about the evilness of `new` and raw pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add a function that gets A **by value**:

```
void f(A a)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then measure the difference between calling it with `std::move` and without:

```
A my_a;
// ...
f(my_a);
f(std::move(my_a));
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after reading up a bit I provided my own examples:

**1)**

When the returned value is also a function parameter, the compiler may use move instead of eliding.

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

```
In a return statement or a throw-expression, if the compiler cannot
perform copy elision but the conditions for copy elision are met or would 
be met, except that the source is a function parameter, the compiler will
attempt to use the move constructor even if the object is designated by an lvalue;
```

And so I think this makes for a pretty convincing demonstration, even in release with optimization flags enabled.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int *buff;
    A(int x) {
        cout << "A::constructor\n";
        buff = new int[1000000];
        buff[0] = x;
    }
    A(const A& a) {
        cout << "A::copy constructor\n";
        buff = new int[1000000];
        memcpy(buff, a.buff, 1000000*sizeof(int));
    }
    A(A&& original)
    {
        cout << "Move constructor" << endl;
        buff = original.buff;
        original.buff = nullptr;
    }
    ~A() { cout << "A::destructor\n"; delete[] buff; }
};

A getA(A temp)
{
    temp.buff[0]++; // configure A
    return temp; // then return it
}

int main() {
    cout << getA(A(7)).buff[0] << endl; // calls move
}
```

Note that in the above case, if there is no move constructor available, the compiler still cannot perform copy elision, and will call the copy constructor.

**2.**

Another extremely simple and common example of the move constructor being called is pushing an RValue with a move constructor to an STL container such as a vector:

```
struct  A
{
    A() { cout << "Default Constructor\n"; }
    A(const A& original) { cout << "Copy constructor\n"; }
    A(A&& original) { cout << "Move constructor\n";  }
};
   
int main() {
    vector<A> v1;
    v1.push_back(A()); // calls move
    return 0;
}
```

In these cases the function is overloaded for RValue and LValue parameters. The RValue version can safely force the move, because it received an RValue, and it does nothing further with it other than add it to the container. We can simulate this with a simplified 1 element version of vector to demonstrate:

```
struct MyVector {
    // a simplified "vector" that can hold only 1 element
    A* data = nullptr;
    void push_back(const A& a) {
        data = new A(a);
    }
    void push_back(A&& a) {
        data = new A(move(a)); // force move
    }
};

int main() {
    MyVector m;
    A a1;
    m.push_back(a1); // calls copy
    m.push_back(A()); // calls move
    return 0;
}
```

**3.**

Another rare situation in which the compiler cannot elid and a move constructor will be called is if the object is volatile:

```
struct  A
{
    A() { cout << "Default Constructor\n"; }
    A(volatile A& original) { cout << "Copy constructor\n"; }
    A(volatile A&& original) { cout << "Move constructor\n"; }
};

A getA() {
    volatile A temp;
    return temp; // not elided - move constructor called
}

int main() {
    A a1 = getA();
    return 0;
}
```